# graphql throws unknown argument error

Tags: graphql

It seems like I'm not getting something fundamental with graphql.

I am trying to get a user by it's id which is in turn the result of another query. In this case a query on some session data.

I don't understand why the error occurs.

Here's my code:

```
{
    session(key: "558fd6c627267d737d11e758f1ae48cae71fc9b584e2882926ad5470c88d7c3ace08c9c7") {
        userId
        expires
        user(id: userId) {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

And I get

**Unknown argument "id" on field "user" of type "Session"**

My schema looks like this:

```
type Session {
    userId: String,
    expires: String,
    user: User
}

type User {
    _id: String
    name: String
    email: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}

type Query {
    session(key: String!): Session
    user(id: String!): User
}
```

**Addendum Feb 23 2017**

I apologize that I wasn't sufficiently explicit about the corresponding resolvers in my initial post. Yes, I my resolvers are defined and e. g. the query works for session if I don't add users.

Here's my root:

```
{
    Query: {
        async user(parentValue, args, req) {
            let user = await adapters.users.byId(args.id);
            return user;
        },
        async session(parentValue, args, req) {
            let session = await adapters.session(args.key);
            let userId = session.session.userId;
            let expires = session.expires;
            return {userId: userId, expires: expires};
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create some `resolver` function on field `user` in type `Session`, because GraphQL does not know how to return the `user`. In `graphql-js` it would look like that

```js
const Session = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Session',
    fields: {
        userId: { type: GraphQLString },
        expires: { type: GraphQLString },
        user: {
            type: User, // it is your GraphQL type
            resolve: function(obj, args, context){
                // obj is the session object returned by ID specified in the query
                // it contains attributes userId and expires
                // however graphql does not know you want to use the userId in order to retrieve user of this session
                // that is why you need to specify the value for field user in type Session
                return db.User.findById(obj.userId).then(function(user){
                    return user;
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It is just a simple example from Node.js to show you how you could return the `user` instance. You have the possibility of specifying how to retrieve values of every field in each GraphQL type (each field can have it's own `resolve` function).

I suggest you read the GraphQL documentation concerning [`root and resolvers`](http://graphql.org/learn/execution/#root-fields-resolvers)

**EDIT**

I will show you an example how you can deal with such a situation. Let's consider two types: `User` and `Session`

```
type User {
    _id: String
    name: String
}

type Session {
    expires: String
    user: User
}
```

If you want your query to return `Session` object together with it's `User`, you do not need to include the `userId` field in `Session` type.
You can solve this situation in two ways. First one is to use single resolver for the `session` query.

```js
{
    Query: {
        async session(parentValue, args, req) {
            let session = await adapters.session(args.key);
            // now you have your session object with expires and userId attributes
            // in order to return session with user from query, you can simply retrieve user with userId
            let user = await adapter.users.byId(session.userId);
            return { expires: session.expires, user: user }
        }
    }
}
```

This is your first option. With that solution you can return `session` object with `user` assigned to it via single query and without extra `resolve` methods on any fields of `Session` type. The second solution is the one I have shown previously, where you use `resolve` method on field `user` of `Session` type - so you simply tell GraphQL how it should obtain the value for this field.

Comment: Ok, my fault, I thought it goes without saying that there are resolvers for each query. If I wouldn't have resolvers, the programm would even crash before this error message. But for the sake of completeness and explicity, I will add my resolvers to the code above.

The query works, if I simply query for session without user.

One other thing: I am using Apollo's graphql-tools for schema definition, so it's definition is based on the GraphQL type language. Have a look at the addendum from Feb 23 2017

Comment: I edited the answer to provide an example for your case